# How to rewrite a default line detection filter to work on any pixel width rather than one pixel wide objects

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I'm trying to detect horizontal lines using built in Matlab functions. Ive read that the filter: `w = [-1 -1 -1;2 2 2;-1 -1 -1]` when applied to an image will detect horizontal lines 1 pixel wide. As its response will be higher in the horizontal direction and in other cases its response will be zero.

My problem is that the lines I want to detect are more than 1 pixel wide. For example I want to detect the white lines in this image:

[image]

Now if I apply the above filter on this image using:

```
lines = imfilter(img, w);
imshow(lines)
```

It produces the following result:

[image]

It has worked as expected i.e it has detected horizontal lines 1 pixel thick and I guess that is why it has only detected the edges or boundaries of the lines. I want it to detect the full white line.

So how do I accomplish this? How do I only make the lines my region of interest and then work on them alone?

One way I think for this to work is that I somehow find out the pixel width of the white lines and then make a new kernel to work on those dimensions but how do I find the pixel width? how do I make a new kernel for said width?

or am I on a completely wrong path?

Comment: I see that you un-accepted my answer, did you encounter problems? See my edit, I added a black frame around the image to isolate the lines.

Comment: Hi Jigg, yes sorry about that. I did accept your answer after the edit. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `bwmorph` function.

Example:

```
skel=bwmorph(bwmorph(YourImage,'erode', 6),'skel', Inf);
imshow(skel)
```

Result:

[image: skeleton of lines]

**Edit** If you are after the position and length of the lines, you can use `regionprops`, like this:

```
Framed = padarray(YourImage,[3 3],0,'both');
```

(This adds a black frame around the image to isolate the individual lines).

```
props=regionprops(Framed, 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox');
centroids={props.Centroid};
BBoxes={props.BoundingBox};
```

The positions of the lines are in the second element of each vector in `centroids`, the length of the lines can be deduced from the bounding boxes in `BBoxes`.

You can plot the results like this:

```
imshow(Framed)
hold on;
for k=1:length(centroids)
    line([1 BBoxes{k}(3)],[centroids{k}(2) centroids{k}(2)])
end
hold off;
```

Result:

[image: Lines drawn on top of image]